# Restrict downloads to authenticated users - IIS, Asp.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-identity, virtual-directory

I have two virtual directories under my site in IIS 7.5.

Unauthenticated users should not be allowed to access these files.

We are using ASP.NET Identity for authentication for the site if this has any bearing on the answer.

A lot of answers/googling seem to point towards using forms authentication in web.config, but As far as i know, ASP.NET Identity doesn't use this.

How would i go about doing this?

EDIT:

Some more info. These two virtual directories are set up in IIS with a specific user in the Physical Path Credentials.

Answer (score 3):

In your virtual directory, you need create a web.config file with this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web >
    <appSettings>
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: appSettings tag can be deleted

Comment: Whilst this works in my use case, This would block unauthenticated access for any web app right?

Comment: Yes, block the access for unauthenticated

Comment: this code block the access for all users...

<deny users=" * "/>

Comment: Actually it isn't working properly. Whilst it does block access to Unauthenticated users, it's also blocking access to authenticated ones as well.  i have <allow users="*"/> in there.

Comment: 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.

Comment: Strange that it's a 401 and not a 403

Comment: You can configure the access to virtual directory.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wce3kxhd.aspx

Comment: remove <allow users="*"/> on your virtual directories

Comment: Why? According to the docs, that's what i want. Allowing access to all authenticated users?

Comment: Ok, then you can remove "<deny users="?"/>" and deny the access for all user Unauthenticated.
Excuse me if I dont understand  to you

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately still not working. Even tried doing it by creating Location elements in my applications web.config, and it's still allowing access for all unauthenticated users. I must have an IIS setting that's causing problems

Comment: I am not sure what the problem is here, but this does work. Of course if your site is public, you don't put this in your 'base' web.config. Add a new folder in your (mvc) application, add a web.config file in that folder, put above code in it, put a secret file in it and you won't be able to open that file when not authenticated. `<deny users="*"/>` will deny any user, is useful if you want to allow specific roles.